# How to convert csv file to tab delimited .txt file using c#

Tags: csv, export-to-text

This is because I have some fields like address in csv which contains comma in the middle of the field.
If I directly copy from csv to text,  tabs are also copying. but
If I use 
File.copy("xxx.csv","xyz.txt");
It is not copying tabs.

Comment: `File.Copy` does not change the content of the file. It simply copies that content, including tabs, commas and any other information in the file. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you're having.

Comment: By selecting all the data and copying in .txt file, it includes tab between every field. But If I copy through code it is not including tab between the fields. Is there any solution in c# that should include tab between the fields while transferring data from .csv to .txt

Comment: As I said, `File.Copy()` does not remove tabs or anything else from the file. Can you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Also, you seem to be misunderstanding something. `File.Copy` does not add tabs to convert a .csv (comma separated value) file to a tab-delimited file. It simply copies the file to a new name - it does not change the file to a dfferent format. I don't know what *selecting all of the data and copying in .txt file* means, because I don't know where you're *selecting* and *copying* from or to, but I do know that `File.Copy` just makes a copy of the existing file to a new file with a new name; it does not add or remove anything, and it does not change formats or content.